# Loading multiple CSVs into QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, csv, import

I've been searching for the fastest way to load multiple CSV Files into QGIS 3.10.

My CSV-files consist of 5 columns:

```
Brand Name | Branch Name | Address | Latitude | Longitude
```

I am using Mac, and `"files:///"` might not work. Any suggestions?

I saw code related to this, and followed this. Here's what I came up with:

```py
import glob, os

csv_files="Users/ajie/Documents/RestoBrand_Py/SAMPLE CSVs/"
os.chdir(csv_files)

for fname in glob.glob("*csv"):
   uri = "files:///" + csv_files + fname + "?delimiter=%s&crs=epsg:4326&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (",",",",",","x","y")
   name = fname.replace('csv', '')
   lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, 'delimitedtext')
   QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

Here's the error

[image]

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots for error messages, copy the text and paste it into your questions and use code formatting.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: You have 3 format operators `%s` and 8 format arguments `(",",",",",","x","y")`. Your `xField` & `yField` should be `"Longitude"` and `"Latitude"` not `"x"` and `"y"`

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments by @user2856, there are too many arguments in the format call. To make the process more transparent, you can hard-code all the parameters. This should work (though not tested on Mac):

```py
import os

directory = "Users/ajie/Documents/RestoBrand_Py/SAMPLE CSVs/"
 
def load_and_configure(path):
    path = os.path.join(directory, filename)
    uri = 'file:///' + path + "?type=csv&escape=&useHeader=yes&detectTypes=yes"
    uri = uri + "&crs=EPSG:4326&xField=Longitude&yField=Latitude"
    vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(uri, filename, "delimitedtext")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
 
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith(".csv"):
        load_and_configure(filename)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool QGIS plugin that does so. It's name is [CSV Batch Import](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/csv_batch_import/).